# Obtener información de nodos de archivo XML

Tags: php

Estoy entrando a este gran mundo del desarrollo con PHP, la necesidad es leer los valores de los nodos de un archivo XML. Solo que en la opciones que estoy colocando muestra la misma información.
Primero no se si es la forma correcta de leer el archivo, pero no puedo acceder a los nodos hijo y a su vez a la información que necesito.

```
    <?php 

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    
    $myXMLData = 'ejemplo.xml';
    
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($myXMLData);
    $firstAttribute = $xml->attributes();
    echo "<pre>".print_r($firstAttribute,1)."</pre><br>";
    
    
    $secondAttribute = $xml->children();
    echo "<pre>".print_r($secondAttribute,1)."</pre>";
```

Y lo unico que estoy obteniendo es lo siguiente:
Version, moneda, folio, lugar de expedición...

O debe de realizar algo adicional para obtener toda la información, como: cfdi:Emisor y todas sus propiedades y todos los nodos posteriores.

Este es el archivo XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/4/cfdv40.xsd" Version="4.0" Moneda="MXN" Folio="1949394" LugarExpedicion="55718" Exportacion="01" MetodoPago="PUE" FormaPago="01" SubTotal="10.04" Descuento="3.47" Total="13.51" TipoDeComprobante="I" Fecha="2023-08-08T13:26:38">
  <cfdi:Emisor Rfc="XAXX01010100" Nombre="ABARROTERO" RegimenFiscal="601"/>
  <cfdi:Receptor Rfc="XAXX010101000" Nombre="JUAN" UsoCFDI="G03" DomicilioFiscalReceptor="54926" RegimenFiscalReceptor="621"/>
  <cfdi:Conceptos>
    <cfdi:Concepto ClaveProdServ="50211502" NoIdentificacion="1402056" Cantidad="5.000000" ClaveUnidad="H87" Unidad="PZA" Descripcion="CIGARRO MARLBORO FUSION SUMMER 10-20 PZ" ValorUnitario="48.96" Importe="244.78" ObjetoImp="02">
      <cfdi:Impuestos>
        <cfdi:Traslados>
          <cfdi:Traslado Base="244.78" Impuesto="002" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Importe="39.17"/>
        </cfdi:Traslados>
      </cfdi:Impuestos>
    </cfdi:Concepto>
    <cfdi:Concepto ClaveProdServ="50211502" NoIdentificacion="1402003" Cantidad="5.000000" ClaveUnidad="H87" Unidad="PZA" Descripcion="CIGARROS MARLBORO ROJO 10-20 PZ" ValorUnitario="55.16" Importe="275.78" ObjetoImp="02">
      <cfdi:Impuestos>
        <cfdi:Traslados>
          <cfdi:Traslado Base="275.78" Impuesto="002" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Importe="44.12"/>
        </cfdi:Traslados>
      </cfdi:Impuestos>
    </cfdi:Concepto>
    <cfdi:Concepto ClaveProdServ="50311502" NoIdentificacion="1504440" Cantidad="5.000000" ClaveUnidad="H87" Unidad="PZA" Descripcion="CIGARROS PALL MALL ALASKA DUST 10-20 PZ Promocion" ValorUnitario="53.90" Importe="269.48" ObjetoImp="02" Descuento="13.47">
      <cfdi:Impuestos>
        <cfdi:Traslados>
          <cfdi:Traslado Base="256.01" Impuesto="002" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Importe="40.96"/>
        </cfdi:Traslados>
      </cfdi:Impuestos>
    </cfdi:Concepto>
  </cfdi:Conceptos>
  <cfdi:Impuestos TotalImpuestosTrasladados="124.25">
    <cfdi:Traslados>
      <cfdi:Traslado Impuesto="002" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Importe="124.25" Base="776.57"/>
    </cfdi:Traslados>
  </cfdi:Impuestos>
  <cfdi:Complemento>
    <tfd:TimbreFiscalDigital xmlns:tfd="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/TimbreFiscalDigital/TimbreFiscalDigitalv11.xsd" Version="1.1" UUID="938CBDAE-650C-4712-93D4-860FC693CBFB" FechaTimbrado="2023-08-08T13:26:43"/>
  </cfdi:Complemento>
</cfdi:Comprobante>
```

Comment: Hola JuanCHM, bienvenido, la pregunta/respuesta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, te sugiero que la edites, y la adaptes a los requerimientos del sitio, para que no sea cerrada, y evitar recibir votos negativos, (códigos, explicaciones y mensajes de error, como texto), mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @MarcePuente, Gracias por el apoyo.

Comment: sigo sin entender por que usan la etiqueta de javascript en algo que no tiene que ver con javascript que mania ...

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 @ gracias por el aporte y tu apoyo. Estoy leyendo mas sobre SimpleXML.
Solo que sigo sin poder ingresas a los nodos con los que me ayudaste. Se me ocurrio una  idea pero solo pude acceder a los namespace del primer nodo, todos los demas se quedan en blanco. Este es el codigo que utilice para los namesapce:
`$namespaces = $xml->getDocNamespaces(TRUE);
echo "NameSpace 1: ".$namespaces['cfdi']."<br>";
echo "NameSpace 2: ".$namespaces['xsi']."<br>";
echo "NameSpace 3: ".$namespaces['tfd']."<br>";
`

Comment: dame un ejemplo de uno de los nodos nietos asumo que no puedes acceder...

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Ya pude acceder a los hijos encontrando los name space oara la entrada de los nodos hijos, muchas gracias por el aporte, como mencionabas hay que empaparse de la documentacion. Saludos

Comment: @JuanCHM espero que te haya servido la respuesta, si es así marca como solucion/resuelta para que otros puedan encontrarla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede decir que vas más o menos en el camino correcto... estás accediendo a los nodos y atributos en la raíz del archivo XML, como "Version", "Moneda", etc.

Sin embargo, para acceder a los nodos secundarios (hijos) como "cfdi:Emisor" y "cfdi:Receptor", necesitas usar una notación especial debido al espacio de nombres (namespace) presente en el XML.

Para mí al principio los espacios de nombre me rompían la cabeza hasta que entendí cómo va el asunto, implemento la función [`children`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/simplexmlelement.children.php) junto con el namespace "cfdi" para acceder a los nodos hijos con el namespace "cfdi". Luego, accedemos a los atributos de los nodos hijos como lo hiciste en la raíz.

```
<?php

$myXMLData = 'ejemplo.xml';

$xml = simplexml_load_file($myXMLData);

// Acceder a atributos en la raíz del XML
$version = $xml['Version'];
$moneda = $xml['Moneda'];
$folio = $xml['Folio'];
$lugarExpedicion = $xml['LugarExpedicion'];

echo "Version: $version<br>";
echo "Moneda: $moneda<br>";
echo "Folio: $folio<br>";
echo "Lugar de Expedición: $lugarExpedicion<br>";

// Acceder a los nodos hijos con namespace
$emisor = $xml->children('cfdi', true)->Emisor;
$receptor = $xml->children('cfdi', true)->Receptor;

// Acceder a los atributos de los nodos hijos
$rfcEmisor = $emisor['Rfc'];
$nombreEmisor = $emisor['Nombre'];

$rfcReceptor = $receptor['Rfc'];
$nombreReceptor = $receptor['Nombre'];

echo "RFC Emisor: $rfcEmisor<br>";
echo "Nombre Emisor: $nombreEmisor<br>";

echo "RFC Receptor: $rfcReceptor<br>";
echo "Nombre Receptor: $nombreReceptor<br>";
```

Si vas a trabajar mucho con los XML te recomiendo estudiar un poco sobre: [SimpleXml](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.simplexml.php)